# Différence entre "Elle versera le tout" vs "Elle versera tout"

Tags: usage, articles

> Elle versera **tout** dans le saladier.
>
> Elle versera **le tout** dans le saladier.

Quelle phrase est plus correcte ? Quelle est la différence entre ces deux tournures ?

Comment: Les deux sont correctes mais ne signifient pas la même chose, quel est le contexte ?

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto Ça fait partie du devoir de ma fille (ce1). Le contexte est hors du sujet de ma question. Il y a quelques phrases et la maîtresse lui demande de les remettre au passé composé/présent/futur simple. Ma fille a vu "Elle versera le tout dans le saladier." et m'a posé la question pourquoi "le tout". Voici alors ma question chez FSE:-)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le mot "tout" peut être pronom, nom, adverbe ou déterminant.

D'après [l'Office québecois de la langue française](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2911) :

> Employé comme pronom invariable, tout désigne un ensemble de choses; il s’emploie habituellement sans antécédent.
>
> *Il avait tellement faim qu’il a tout mangé.*

Et d'après [la même source](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5165) :

> Le nom tout peut servir à exprimer la totalité, la somme des parties.
>
> *Nous prendrons le tout.*

Telles que je comprends ces définitions, la différence est subtile mais bien existante. On emploierait "tout" pour désigner un ensemble de choses **ne constituant pas nécessairement la totalité**, alors que "le tout" serait employé pour **exprimer la totalité**.

Pour reprendre le contexte de la question, voici deux exemples dans lesquels j'emploierais "tout" ou "le tout":

> 1. Quand elle aura fini de préparer les boulettes, elle en prendra la moitié puis elle versera **tout** (*tout parmi cette moitié*) dans le saladier. Comme ça, on pourra faire cuire une partie de la viande sans attendre !
> 2. Pour réaliser cette recette, ma fille devra d'abord préparer la farine, l'eau et les oeufs en les pesant soigneusement. Puis elle versera **le tout** (*la totalité*) dans le saladier, avant de le mélanger jusqu'à obtenir une belle pâte.